# Using two timers Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have to do a C++ code to use two Qt timers:

- one as an alarm, after x seconds, call a c function alarm_finished().
- one to implement this: every second, call callback on_1s_event also defined in a c file.

I know that I should use two timers, and class QTimer but I'm not sure either to define the two timers in two different classes or not, and how can I guarantee that my timers are running in the same time, that one doesn't wait for the other. Thank you so much for enlightening me around this matter!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the `connect` command of Qt? Do you have a Qt Main Loop?

Comment: You can use 2 timers or 1 in the same class. Either method would work. You could use 1 timer then count how many seconds elapsed in your slot and fire an event that triggers the alarm.

Comment: Why you have to use 2 timers? Use one timer e.g. 500ms then increase a counter and if the counter == 2 then 1s is elapsed and execute the function, same for other times.

Answer (score 2):

QTimer doesn't promise to be *exact*, but if you are measuring with a resolution of seconds, it will be very good for normal uses.

> how can I guarantee that my timers are running in the same time, that one doesn't wait for the other.

You don't. If `alarm_finished` takes multiple seconds to run, there will be multiple seconds where `on_1s_event` doesn't fire. Similarly if `on_1s_event` takes more than a second to run, your system is not going to function correctly.

Comment: If the timer-slots take a long enough time to return that it’s a problem, the problem could be addressed by having them run in different threads.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner if you start >1s of work per second, you will quickly run out of cores to run those threads

Comment: True, but I don’t think there is any fix for that except making your program more efficient or buying a faster computer :)

Answer (score 2):

Just for your reference. I am using two QTimers in a test class. In the 10th 1sec task its triggering the 10s alarm.

```
#define TWOTIMER_HPP

#include <QObject>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

class MyTestObject: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyTestObject(): timer_alarm(new QTimer()),
        periodic_call(new QTimer())
    {

        periodic_call->setInterval(1000);
        timer_alarm->setSingleShot(true);
        timer_alarm->setInterval(10000);
        connect(periodic_call, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyTestObject::ProcessTask1s_event);
        connect(timer_alarm, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyTestObject::Invoke_Alarm);
        timer_alarm->start();
        periodic_call->start();

    }

    void ProcessTask1s_event()
    {
        qDebug() << "Process Task Ran ";
    }

    void Invoke_Alarm()
    {
        qDebug() << "Invoke Alarm Task Ran ";
    }

private:
    QTimer* timer_alarm;
    QTimer* periodic_call;


};

#endif // TWOTIMER_HPP
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you supplied very sparse information, I'll keep this answer generic.

In your main window, you can create your timers with `new QTimer(this)` as local variables (the `this` will take care of freeing them upon destruction of the main window).

Then, you need to `connect` the timeout event of the QTimer instances to the functions you want to call, such as this:

```
connect(timer1, &QTimer::timeout, &someCFunction);
```

Finally, you need to `start` the timer with the required interval in milliseconds.

Please refer to the documentation at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html for some more details.

Please also note, that Qt utilizes an 'EventLoop' mechanism, meaning that your functions will execute in the same 'thread context' as the receiving context (i.e. your main loop).
As such, your events can be executed 'after one another', but never 'at the same time'.

Comment: If you want to avoid calling ‘new’, adding the QTimer as a member-variable to the class also works well.